Performance Testing with NICE Call Center package
My company is trying to implement call center with NICE. How can we plan for performance testing with NICE ? I would like to capture the time taken the call comes in to Salesforce and a case pops up infront of my agent with peak call volume. Is there any endpoint/webhook which we can use to mimic the incoming call to Salesforce?
